# NFS permissions and slow copy

Tags: openbsd, nfs

I have an NFS share on an OpenBsd server. When I assess the share from my Ubuntu box I don't seem to have all permission eg write. Also copying a file from the NFS share to the Ubuntu machine can take > 1 hour for a 44mb file. Any suggestions?

I exported the share through `/etc/exports`:

```
/home/some_user/downloads -alldirs -maproot=some_user -network=192.168.5.0 -mask=255.255.255.0
```

And mounted the share the following.

```
sudo mount 192.168.5.60:/home/some_user/downloads ~/test
```

Comment: How did you export your share? How did you mount it?

Comment: Oh, OpenBSD exports r/w by default :P Sorry =) Anyway, that means you can't write because of some permission problem.

Comment: I am more concerned with the slow speeds.

Comment: What is the speed of network traffic over other protocols (e.g. scp, http)?

Comment: As fast as one would imagine over a 10/100 network they both perform good.

Answer (score 2):

Increase rsize and wsize on the Ubuntu box (I have put this in `/etc/fstab`):

```
server:/dir  /dir  nfs  rw,soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192  0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

To increase the speed use UDP:

```
sudo mount -o udp 192.168.5.60:/home/some_user/downloads ~/test
```

Try using `mapall=some_user` to see if that solves your permission problem.